# Does the increase of a stat also induce the increase of corresponding skill?

Tags: skills, call-of-cthulhu-7e

If for some reason the EDU stat of a character is increased (for example they get a university diploma during a long downtime period) or (in a less likely event) the DEX stat is altered, does that also impose a change of, respectively, Language (OWN) and Dodge skills?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### As per RAW, no

Changes in attributes occur because of aging (Core Rulebook p. 98). There's no mention of adjustments to current skill scores, so it's safe to assume attribute scores determine only **starting** skill scores (even if the change happens because of an accident, a scar, magic...).

On a side note, studying for a long time wouldn't increase EDU but would give you an advancement check in the skill you were studying (or practicing, or whatever). (also p. 98)

### Nevertheless, CoC rules can be easily hacked (and usually are)

Being an old game system with few radical changes since the 1st edition, the BRP is usually seen as a toolbox whose elements you can chose to ignore without risking to hurt the game's balance. I'd say the only crucial element that shouldn't be tampered with is the sanity (and even that could be replaced with a more elaborate but similar system like the ones in Trail of Cthulhu or Delta Green).

So if you feel like it would make sense to reduce a skill score if the investigator had an accident, just do so (as with any hack, you should make this rule change very clear before you start playing).

Personally, I wouldn't do it, I think the game is gritty enough without disabling the characters even more (they're pretty powerless to begin with, that's the point of the game). If there's a loss of DEX, I'd consider the character to be smart enough to have learned how to compensate slower reflexes with better anticipation, for instance.